# addon sdk update simple-prefs value

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, preference

Is it possible to programmatically set a `simple-prefs` value?
Or should I be using `preferences/service` which contains [set(name, value)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/preferences/service.html#set%28name,%20value%29)?

This is the `simple-prefs` I would like to set:

```
{
    "name": "pathToFile",
    "title": "Path to file?",
    "type": "directory",
    "value": ""
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

White it isn't obvious from the documentation, but [`simple-prefs.prefs`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/simple-prefs.html#prefs) is actually a [`Branch`](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/master/lib/sdk/preferences/service.js#L25), which in turn is a full Javascript proxy around the underlying XPCOM preference service.

So it is possible to just set any preference to a `Number` (`Integer`), `Boolean` or `String`, e.g.

```
const {prefs} = require("simple-prefs");
console.log("before", prefs.pref1, prefs["pref2"]); 
prefs.pref1 = "some string";
prefs["pref2"] = 2;
console.log("after", prefs.pref1, prefs["pref2"]);
```

Comment: `console.log(require("simple-prefs")["pathToFile"]);` results in `console.log: addon: undefined`

Comment: `.prefs` as in `console.log(require("simple-prefs").prefs["pathToFile"]);`

Comment: `require("simple-prefs").prefs["pathToFile"] = "test";` did the trick